# Already in all tenses

Tags: grammaticality

Can "already" be used in other tenses?

For examples:

Is it possible if I use "already" in all progressive tenses?

E.g.

> He is already flying his plane
>
> He was already flying his plane.
>
> He will already flying his plane.

and I'm not sure that it can be used like those,

E.g.

> I would have *already* played it (or) I will have *already* played it.

So, when can I use "already"?

Comment: *He will already **be** flying his plane* -- progressive requires the auxiliary *BE*.

Answer (score 4):

*Already* may be used in any non-negative context, with any verb construction, simple, progressive, or perfect, with any time reference: it designates the time you are speaking about (technically, Reference Time).

> He's already flying his plane.
>   He had already flown his plane.
>   At 6 pm he will already have been flying his plane for two hours.

In negative contexts, however, it is replaced with *yet*, unless you are explicitly contradicting a prior assertion with *already*.

> He is not yet flying his plane *or* He is not flying his plane yet.
>   *but*
>   What do you mean, he's already flying his plane? He's **not** already flying his plane—he hasn't even left the hangar!

Answer (score 1):

The adverb **already** is used to refer to a past action, or an ongoing or habitual action that *started* in the past. Therefore, it may be used with any tense that references the past, the present or the continuous. This includes all simple tenses, all perfect tenses and all progressive tenses, but note the following.

When referring to a point in the past (past tenses or perfect tenses), already can be used with either an action (doing verb) or a state (being verb).

When referring to a point in the present (simple present, simple future, or progressive) it can only really be used with a state*. The caveat to this is when using simple present to refer to a habitual action, when a doing verb may be used. Note that when using simple future, there must be a reference point in the future for the *already* to make sense.

> I will already be gone - Doesn't really make sense (unless this is a response to a question that defines the time reference); when will you already be gone?
>
> I will already be gone by tomorrow - OK
>
> I will already play football by tomorrow - Doesn't really make sense

*(Progressive tenses always use an auxiliary [be] because they refer to a state of doing something)

Comment: So, if I use the sentence like this one ,Do you think this is a correct sentence?

"They are/were already learning some Russian before leaving for Moscow."

Comment: @StoneyB Yep, clearly I'm not on it today...

Comment: Sometimes you just need another cup of coffee :)

Comment: @AqshaIsham Yes, that sentence is grammatically correct.

Comment: How about this one e.g I will have already made a house.

Comment: @AqshaIsham Yes, grammatically that's fine. To make sense, the future reference point must be/have been established somewhere. It would make more sense if a "by [time]" was appended (where time = some time, e.g. tomorrow, or then). _I will have already made a house by then._

Comment: @AqshaIsham Also, when talking about the construction of a house (or any other building), it is more common to use the verb _built_ than _made_. And finally, you are probably referring to a specific house, so you should probably use the definite article, or a possessive determiner: _I will have already built the/my house by then._